# No Preview Button

Tags: 2013

just started a new gig with a company that uses Tridion. It's been a while since i've used the CMS, but there is one major change compared to the Tridion i've used in the past. There is no preview button, meaning to check a website in staging I have to manually put in the url or navigate to the page in staging..

Where as, I would, at my previous role, just press "View in Staging" and it would populate. Is this something I should bring up with the company that manages the CMS ? or is there a setting?

after checking the market level properties, i saw that the path was populated but URL was blank (with a single '/' in the field)

the version of Tridion is 2013 and v7.

Cheers.

Comment: In the past you must have had an aftermarket GUI extension installed to allow this. That extension is also available for 2013 sp1. Just look through the plugin app store for it and get your admins to install it

Comment: Awesome, where can one find this app store?

Comment: Cheers! found the app store, it's a free addon as well! brilliant, thanks mate!

Comment: Please self answer your question then, and after a few days you can approve your answer so the question is "closed"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the helpful comments above, it's clear that this is an extra GUI addon from the SDL store (which is free) that would need to be implemented by the web administrator.

Edit,

adding the link : )

https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/2013-view-in-staging-and-live-ui-extension/626/

as others have said, this isn't needed in 8.0!

Comment: BTW in later versions (8.x) this is available in the base product as “view on site”

Comment: Would be nice if you add a link to the extension in the appstore, so it is clear

Comment: done & cheers chaps!